# Postgres restore unclear behaviour

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.4, backup, pg-basebackup

I have following: 2 nodes one of which is current production db and another is for fail recovery. I made base backup on first node with following command `pg_basebackup -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -D bckp -Ft -z -P -R -x` and got bacup file `base.tar.gz`. Now i'm trying to recover it on failover node. I cleared data directory and unzipped there contents of the backup. As I do not need wal logs from master node to stream to this server i should create `recovery.conf` with at least `restore_command` specifying command that will copy wal logs from archive directory to `xp_log`. But it was already there in `xp_log`. There was file `000000010000000000000017`. As i'm new to postgres and linux I decided to move this file to `archive` directory and set `recovery.conf` contents to `restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/postgresql/archive/%f /var/lib/postgresql/data/%p'` then started postgres. It printed ot logs

```
2015-10-26 14:06:16 UTC [16-3] LOG:  starting archive recovery
2015-10-26 14:06:16 UTC [16-4] LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000017" from archive
2015-10-26 14:06:16 UTC [16-5] LOG:  redo starts at 0/17000060
2015-10-26 14:06:16 UTC [16-6] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/17000160
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/postgresql/backup/000000010000000000000018’: No such file or directory
2015-10-26 14:06:16 UTC [16-7] LOG:  redo done at 0/17000160
2015-10-26 14:06:16 UTC [16-8] LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000017" from archive
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/postgresql/backup/00000002.history’: No such file or directory
2015-10-26 14:06:16 UTC [16-9] LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 2
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/postgresql/backup/00000001.history’: No such file or directory
2015-10-26 14:06:16 UTC [16-10] LOG:  archive recovery complete
2015-10-26 14:06:17 UTC [16-11] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2015-10-26 14:06:17 UTC [30-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2015-10-26 14:06:17 UTC [1-2] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Finally it restores and works fine but there are unclear moments for me:
With restoring of `000000010000000000000017` i understand, but why it tries to recover `000000010000000000000018` as it's not there? And what are `00000002.history` and `00000001.history` files and why it tries to find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regard to your questions, please read the documentation completely, as it addresses all of your concerns.

In terms of looking for `000000010000000000000018` when it doesn't exist .. the recovery process just parses all WAL files until it encounters "EOF" .. which usually happens when it tries to read from the next WAL file and it doesn't exist..  So it uses that case as a termination point for the recovery process..  The important bit here is that it reached a checkpoint in the recovery process as stated with `consistent recovery state reached at 0/17000160`.  This means that your recovery is reliable.

[Continuous Archiving Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/continuous-archiving.html) Section 24.3.5. - Timelines

Timelines are a way for Postgres to handle "alternate universes" so to speak...  For example, if you have a situation where your replication gets messed up in some way and suddenly you have slave promoted into master status (while your master never went down) ... some machines are writing to the master still while some are writing to the slave..  But it's ok, because the writes to the current master will all happen on timeline 1 and the writes to the slave will all happen on timeline 2 .. so you can, theoretically, still merge all the changes together (although I'm sure it wouldn't be easy)..  I imagine it's similar to a branch in a version control system.  Except there's no real "trunk".

For the postgres gurus out there - if I have anything incorrect, please correct me.  :)

Comment: i've read the docs several times and found nothing about this situation :( first of all what command i should provide as `restore_command` as wal logs are already there? i moved them to another directory but it' seems to be a dumb solution. and you didn't mention `.history` files in your response. what is their purpose?

Comment: The .history files are the timeline files..  It says in the link I posted under section 24.3.5 ... Quoting: `Every time a new timeline is created, PostgreSQL creates a "timeline history" file that shows which timeline it branched off from and when. These history files are necessary to` .. The restore command is only necessary if you are offloading your replication WAL files in a non standard way.  You shouldn't need to supply a restore command when bringing the slave up to master status..  Read `24.3.4. Recovering Using a Continuous Archive Backup` of above link..

Comment: Oh - I just realized you're probably not doing streaming replication.  Anyway - if you supplied an archive_command to archive your WAL files (Section `24.3.1. Setting Up WAL Archiving`) .. then you'd need a restore command to undo whatever archive_command you supplied.  If you didn't supply an archive_command, then you don't need a restore_command..

Comment: `archive_command` just copies files to archive directory and i have one set to `test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/archive/%f && cp /var/lib/postgresql/data/%p /var/lib/postgresql/archive/%f`. No, i cannot omit `restore_command` if i want archive recovery. in `recovery.conf.sample` file there is line that states "This parameter is *required* for an archive recovery"

Comment: You have an archive_command set ..... then provide a restore_command that undoes what the archive_command does..  The parameter might be required, but that doesn't mean it has to DO anything.  AFAIK, `restore_Command=` is perfectly valid (although I could easily be incorrect there, since I've never tried it).  Anyway - do you understand what your archive_command does?  If you do, then creating a restore command should be easy to figure out...  If you don't, then perhaps you should read through it and research what your archive_command is doing..

Comment: my archive command copies wal files from xp_log directory to archive directory and my restore command does the opposite so i do not see any inconsistencies

Comment: It sounds like all of your questions have been addressed, then?